# How to boot windows in Mac?

Tags: windows-7, osx-lion, boot-camp, windows-8-preview

I have this strange problem, where I have two Windows installed on my MBP in two different partitions

[image]

`Untitled Windows` is Win8, `Bootcamp windows` is Windows 7 and Mac OS X

Whenever I choose to boot from any of the windows disk, the MacBook always boots from Windows 8. No matter what startup disk is set! And on the boot screen only MAC OS and Windows are shown, another windows options is missing...

How do I fix it? I don't want loose existing Windows 7 partition

Comment: I'm betting the windows boot loader was overwritten and might not recognize the windows 7 install.

Comment: Don't bet too much, skub.  The effects of _hybrid MBR_ partitioning are still in the running and still have fairly good odds.  Of course, the questioner hasn't provided (in the question) _both_ the output from `diskpart`'s `list partition` and `list disk` commands in Windows _and_ the output from `diskutil list` in MacOS, so there's not enough information supplied for anyone to know.

Comment: Maybe Windows 7 updated to Windows 8 and now both are Windows 8. Try saving a file on the desktop and see if it's on both or just one